# How to place each value of an object into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two objects:

```
a = {A: 1, B: 2};
a = {C: 3, D: 4};
```

I need to put the property values of the objects in to one array. So, i'm doing this by iterate each of the objects, but what next, pushing it into one array returns two separated...

```
$.each(a, function(_key, _val) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(_val);
    console.log(arr);
});
```

How to do this? Is it possible?
I need this: `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fqtkkb7b/

Comment: initialize `var arr = [];` outside each

Comment: Also, your variable name is same for both objects, i.e. `a`, this way `a` will hold only `{C: 3, D: 4}`.

Comment: that's the issue, this is the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the arr inside the each everytime. Try this:

```
var arr = [];
$.each(a, function(_key, _val) {
    arr.push(_val);
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aarLgmtL/

```
var a = {A: 1, B: 2};
var b = {C: 3, D: 4};

function join(source, target) {
    $.each(source, function(_key, _val) {
        target.push(_val);
    });
}

var arr = [];
join(a, arr);
join(b, arr);

$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

You could try using .concat as well. Here is an example from w3schools:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: these arrays have the same 'name'

Comment: in that case, if you are just reassigning new values to the "a" variable, then it will still work, as long as: 1) you define arr outside of the each at least. you are reinitializing it all the time; 2) do the $.each before reassigning. is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize array in `$.each` function. It will assign new array every time $.each function call so it end up with last array element in `arr` variable.

```js
a = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2
};
b = {
  C: 3,
  D: 4
};
var arr = [];

function pushToArray(a) {
  $.each(a, function(_key, _val) {
    arr.push(_val);
  });
}
pushToArray(a);
pushToArray(b);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure that you **don't define different object with same name** else end up with last object assigned to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The approach outlined below first creates two separate arrays, one from `a` and one from `b`, and then concatenates them together (with a little help from the jQuery [`Array#map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method.)

```
a = {A: 1, B: 2};
b = {C: 3, D: 4};

var arrayFromA = $.map(a, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

var arrayFromB = $.map(b, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});

finalArray = arrayFromB.concat(arrayFromA);
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO. Pleas add a bit of an explanation. Also, you're solution does not provide the exact answer to the question as the resulting array is not sorted correctly. Lastly, the variable `array` does not exist. It should be `finaleArray = array2.concat(array1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using Object.assign

```
    var a = {A: 1, B: 2};
    var b = {C: 3, D: 4};
    var copy = Object.assign(a, b);
    var result =[];
    for(var i in copy){
       result.push(copy[i]);
    }
console.log(result);
```

Thanks.